# Hadoop Maven Dependencies for MapReduce

Tags: maven, hadoop, mapreduce

I am trying to write a mapreduce program in a single node cluster (hadoop 2.4). I found maven dependencies for hadoop in maven central repository.

http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hadoop

Which all of these dependencies are necessary (include in pom.xml) to write a map-reduce program ?

thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`hadoop-core` is usually enough to write map-reduce jobs. Since hadoop libraries should be available when you run the job on the cluster, you can add `<scope>provided</scope>` in the dependency.

For Unit tests, you can use `org.apache.mrunit` dependency with `<scope>test</scope>`

Comment: `hadoop-client` is probably a better option as it is distributed for `2.x` versions of Hadoop.